# Highcharts stacked area - update tooltip only after exact area mouse over

Tags: highcharts, stacked-area-chart

I have [stacked area-chart](https://jsfiddle.net/levsha/9yjs3ovw/) made with Highcharts.js. I want to update the tooltip only when the cursor crosses the border between areas. Currently, the tooltip updates when the distance between the cursor and the edge of one area makes closer than the distance between the cursor and the neighbor area edge (see the gif).

How can I reach this behaviour?

[image]

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            trackByArea: true,
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of setting `trackByArea` to true and `stickyTracking` to false is a solution which you are looking for.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e9r2Lmtk/

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      trackByArea: true,
      stickyTracking: false // to show the difference in tracking
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.trackByArea

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.stickyTracking